# C# MVC and jQuery AJAX - having trouble with Form Posts and history issues in general

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got an application that does some nice stuff when a user requests a different page.  Rather than going to that page, it loads the contents of the page into the existing page (using jquery's .load()).  That works great.

My application's controllers work great.  I can request a view and then submit the form, which is routed through the controller and gets submitted back to the db using various model classes.

This all happens fine on their own.

The problem is, if I have a page called /newgranny/ and I navigate to the page from home, the user just sees the root directory in the address bar.  Not desireable.  What's worse, when I submit /newgranny/ form, it doesn't go to /newgranny/, it goes to /, because technically I'm still at the root.  Form doesn't get submitted, data lost.  That's not good.  I'm losing grannies.  The same is true for /updategranny/ or any other page with a form that returns back to itself.

Is there an alternative to the method I'm using?  Is there a js solution to the problem - something cross browser that can handle changing the location without changing the location?

I've looked into history plugins.  All the ones I've seen deal with hashtags.  I don't want to load something that's already present on the page - isn't that what the hashtag is doing?

Failing a solution soon, I intend to remove the .load() and all the resulting coolness it performs alongside it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include your View (especially your controls and JS/JQ)

Comment: Very creative architectural design. For the forms, you could just rely on ajax instead of postbacks for submitting data. As for changing the address bar, there is no current cross-browser solution to my knowledge.

Comment: Cooool.  I can't believe I didn't think to post the form via ajax...very nice!  Thanks Brad M

Comment: It's working brilliantly  now.  In addition, I added two hidden inputs to my forms - one to store where the form should submit to, and one for the page location that should be loaded next.  Sometimes they're the same, but often they're not.  Not sure the hidden fields were the best way to store/retrieve such information, but it works great.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure us this the answer but you tell the form where to POST Html.BeginForm("granny", "Add", FormMethod.Post))

Comment: Ah, nice.   That was very silly of me.  I'm grateful for your suggestion, as well as Brad M's in the comment above.  Either will work nicely!  Thanks!